# We would like to register a user if space is available or put on waiting list if space is full. Any ideas how to approach this?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to create a waiting list.

The idea behind this waiting list is that we have a training problem that requires users to sign up for a seat in the class.

There is a maximum capacity seating of 45 people.

If all 45 seats have been occupied, then available_seating which starts at 45 and decreases per course registration, will be 0.

If available_seating is 0, that means that the class is full and no seatings are available.

When a user attempts to sign up for a class where available_seating = 0, we would want to let the user know that this class is full and 
 s/he will be put on waiting list.

I think I know how to solve this problem.

When available_seating > 0 insert the user into tblTrainings table.

However, if available_seating = 0 then insert user into a table called waitingList.

My problem is how to blend that conditional statement with the counter below.

Below, the SELECT Count(*) query checks to see if user has already registered for a particular class.

If no, register the user for the class. If yes, alert the user that s/he has already registered for the class.

How do I integrate the two in such that we first check to see if the user has already registered for the class.

If no, then we check whether the class is not full yet. If full, insert user into waitingList. If not full, insert user into tblTrainings.

See current code and thanks a lot in advance.

```vb
    'If user already registered for a class, alert user
    s = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tblTrainings WHERE Username = '" & username & "' AND CourseID = " & Request.QueryString("cosId") & "  AND LocationID = " & Request.QueryString("locid") & " AND dateId = " & Request.QueryString("iddate") & ""
    Dim connSt As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim connc As New SqlConnection(connSt)
    Dim cmdc As New SqlCommand(s, connc)
    connc.Open()
    cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery()
    counter = cmdc.ExecuteScalar()


    '   Now let's see if we found existing record
    If counter = 0 Then
        'User hasn't signed up for this class yet

        s = "INSERT INTO tblTrainings (CourseId, tblLocations.LocationId, dateId,AvailableSeats,username) VALUES (@CosID, @LocID, @dat, @Available_Seating, @Username)"
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(s, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cosID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", Request.QueryString("locid"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat", Request.QueryString("iddate"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Available_Seating", 45 - 1)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username)
        conn.Open()
```

Comment: So, if the user has not already signed up for training, then it tries to insert them into tblTrainings, but there is no check to see if the maximum amount people (45) have already signed up, why is that?

If you are trying to setup a scenario where when a user tries to register for training and you want to "block" other users from trying to register at the same time, then you will either want to have SQL be in a stored procedure that has a transaction so it is an all or nothing operation or you will want to actually use a queue mechanism, all depends upon what level of concurrency you want.

Comment: @Karl, recall that I said that I think I know how to solve the problem, that I could solve it by performing a check, if available_seating=0, this means no more seats are available.

However, my issue is how to make it blend with the COUNT(*) query that checks to see if user already registered.

Thanks for the stored proc suggestion. I think it is a great idea. I will probably use that approach once I get this issue resolved.

Comment: Oh so you want one SQL statement that does both checks?

Comment: @Karl, yes if that's possible.

Comment: the `insert` statement could get the values from a `select` statement that also counts the registrations and only returns the values when count is zero.

Comment: can you give example code?

Comment: @Kenny - looks like you have answer below using a nested SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem that complicated to me.

This answer only uses the SQL pieces that matter to preserve legibility, since I'm mainly referring to queries and not the VB.

First, you do what you were already doing--check to see if they're already signed up/on the waiting list.

```sql
SELECT Count(*) FROM (
   SELECT * FROM tblTrainings UNION SELECT * FROM waitingList
) AS t
WHERE Username = XXX AND CourseID = XXX AND LocationID = XXX AND dateID = XXX
/* Tells you whether the person is signed up already, whether for the course itself
or the waiting list. */
```

```sql
SELECT Count(*) FROM tblTrainings
WHERE CourseID = XXX AND LocationID = XXX AND dateID = XXX
-- This will give you the number of people in the course.
```

Then, once you have that, you can decide whether to add them to that table or add them to waiting list.

#### Update

Maybe this will help.

```vb
'Here build your querystring s from the SQL query above, filling in whatever values your need.
s = "SELECT Count(*) FROM (" & _
    "SELECT * FROM tblTrainings UNION SELECT * FROM waitingList" & _
    ") AS t" & _
    "WHERE Username = XXX AND CourseID = XXX AND LocationID = XXX AND dateID = XXX"    

Dim connSt As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim connc As New SqlConnection(connSt)
Dim cmdc As New SqlCommand(s, connc)
connc.Open()
cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery()
counter = cmdc.ExecuteScalar()

If counter = 0 Then 'this means that the person is in neither the waitlist nor courselist
    
    'Fill in the XXX as necessary
    qs = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tblTrainings WHERE CourseID = XXX AND LocationID = XXX AND dateID = XXX"
    Set cmdc = New SqlCommand(s, connc)
    cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery()
    courseSize = cmdc.ExecuteScalar()

    If courseSize <= 45 Then
          'Insert the guy into the course
    Else
          'Insert the guy into waitList
    End If 
End If
```

Comment: will my IF statement still be the same?

For instance, I can continue to say, IF counter = 0, this means that user hasn't signed up for either tblTrainings and is not on waiting list so what???

How do I then decide whether to add the user to training table based on Available_Seating being greater than 0 or to add user to waiting list because now Available_Seating is 0????

That's where I am still confused. Sorry if this seems that easy to you.

Comment: still not working.

Rather than lump entire code here, I will just point out the 2 changes I made.

First, I changed this from `If CourseSize <=45 then...` to `If CourseSize > 0 Then ...` and the other change is I added `WHERE username ='" & username & "'...`. I made this changes because the original code you posted, even though they look great, were giving me same result. If I click insert, first time it goes to waitinglist table. I try again, I get the message that I have already signed up for class. It should only go to waitinglist if CourseSize = 0 and I havn't already sined up

Comment: Well, I think that `If CourseSize > 0` is your problem.  Since `CourseSize` is the number of people signed up for the course, what you're saying is "If _at least one person_ is signed up for this course, then sign this guy up to.  If no one is, then put him on the waiting list."  That's obviously not what you want.  So you end up with two problems: 1) The person isn't signed up for the course if the current enrollment is 0.  2) There's no upper bound at 45--e.g., if 45 people are signed up, a 46th will also be able to sign up.

Comment: again, in my last response, I indicated that I only changed those two things *after* trying your solution which was given me the same result.

Also, if you look at the insert statement into training table, the capacity seating is 45. So, each time a user signs up, the number decrements. So, 45 will continue to decrease each time someone signs up until it is 0. This means that no more seat is available, now go on waiting list. So, I see CourseSize as the current number on training table. As long as that number is not 0, users cans till sign up. That's the logic of the insert code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a TableA and you want to insert a record only when TableB count is zero. Then you could write this:

```
insert into TableA (ColA, ColB) 
select 'a', 'b' from TableB 
 where 0 = (select count(*) 
              from TableB 
             where ColC = 'c')
```

It should be easy to fit the above statement to your scenario.

Comment: @jdotjdot, why are you linking to waitingList in your query? I think that we should be checking tblTrainings to see if available_seating is 0. There should be no limit on watingList table. muratgu, I am confused about your comparison of tableA with tableB. Maybe, I am not being clear. How do I merge that code with the code that checks to see if user has already signed up for a class or not?

I needed to add that it is not just one class but several classes from several locations. So, we need to make sure the user has signed up for correct class from the correct location.

Comment: @kenny: why confused? you create a select which returns number of rows for whatever condition from whatever table (you already have this). if it returns 0, then it inserts a record into a target table (you have that one too).

Comment: I am checking for TWO conditions. HOW do I check the TWO conditions at SAME time BEFORE deciding whether to insert into either tblTrainings or WaitingList?

Comment: I totally misunderstood what you were after. I thought you were asking how to do the count and insert in one step. Ignore my answer.